# Array merge recursive with an variable index

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, merge

I need to merge secuentially different arrays.

Let's say I have 3 and 2 arrays I need to merge all together. Currently I am using this:

```
$ppjson_data= json_encode(array_merge_recursive($ppposts[0][0],$ppposts[0][1],$ppposts[0][2],$ppposts[1][0],$ppposts[1][1]));
```

This works great.

Now the problem is that the number of arrays I may need to merge is not constant. There are $x and $y arrays to merge recursively, so how would you do it?

```
$x=5;
$y=10;
for ($i=0;$i<$x+1) {
  for ($j=0;$j<$y+1) {    
    $ppjson_data=json_encode(array_merge_recursive(...));
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `array_merge_recursive` with the sub-arrays of your array as arguments using `call_user_func_array`:

```
$ppjson_data = json_encode(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $ppposts));
```

That creates an arra, in JSON it will be surrounded in `[]`.  If you want an object instead `{}` then cast it with `(object)`:

```
$ppjson_data = json_encode((object)call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $ppposts));
```

Comment: Almost done, but the resulting json starts with     "[" and finishes with     "]". Any chances to avoid that?

Comment: I prefer the previous one and then:      $ppjson_data=str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $ppjson_data)

Comment: Depends on what you need, that might not be valid JSON.  Check https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: In my case, it is valid. Thank you!